# How do I get all the different unique combinations of 3 columns using VBA in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel worksheet with several columns, where 3 of them form a "unique key".
If I have fruits in column A (Apple, Banana, Orange), some name in column B (John, Peter) and something like Yes/No in column C, I want to be able to get sums of values from rows where the values in these columns are the same.
For instance, the sum of all the values in column D for rows where columns A, B and C are Apple,John,Yes.

Sorry for the confusing text, but I don't know how to express my question more clearly. I've never done anything in VBA so I'm a bit lost here...

Here's an example of the expected result.
[image: Expected result]

Comment: Take a look at the `SUMIFS` function.

Comment: As this isn't using VBA, I've added as a comment.
In 2007 or later  you can use SUMIFS as Doug has mentioned:
**=SUMIFS($D$1:$D$6,$A$1:$A$6,"Apple",$B$1:$B$6,"John",$C$1:$C$6,"Yes")**
In 2003 you can use SUMPRODUCT:
**=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$6="Apple")*($B$1:$B$6="John")*($C$1:$C$6="Yes")*$D$1:$D$6)**

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @Darren, the thing is, I don't know in advance which combinations exist. The goal is to list all the unique combinations and the sum of some other columns. Can I do this without using VBA?

Comment: Something showing sample data and expected results would help us understand.

Comment: You are right, I added a simple image to the original post. How do I generate rows like those on the right for every unique combination on the data source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't know in advance which combinations exist. The goal is to list all the unique combinations and the sum of some other columns. Can I do this without using VBA?

No Formulas/VBA required. Use a Pivot table for a summary of all combinations. See screenshot

[image]

If you still want VBA then that can also be done :)

**EDIT**

I quickly wrote this

```
Sub sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim Itm
    Dim cField As String

    Const deLim As String = "#"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            cField = .Range("A" & i).Value & deLim & _
                     .Range("B" & i).Value & deLim & _
                     .Range("C" & i).Value

            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add cField, CStr(cField)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i

        i = 2

        .Range("A1:C1").Copy .Range("F1")
        .Range("I1").Value = "Count"

        For Each Itm In col
            .Range("F" & i).Value = Split(Itm, deLim)(0)
            .Range("G" & i).Value = Split(Itm, deLim)(1)
            .Range("H" & i).Value = Split(Itm, deLim)(2)


            For j = 2 To lRow
                cField = .Range("A" & j).Value & deLim & _
                         .Range("B" & j).Value & deLim & _
                         .Range("C" & j).Value

                If Itm = cField Then nCount = nCount + 1
            Next
            .Range("I" & i).Value = nCount

            i = i + 1
            nCount = 0
        Next Itm
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really close to what I want. Is there anyway to display it as cells, similar to my example? Because this data would then be used for other purposes. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: For the exact format that you require then you need VBA

Comment: Refresh the page. I have provided a VBA example as well

Comment: your VBA code counts the number of rows, but I think I can adapt it to calculate the sums of other columns. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible to go to the data tab -> remove duplicates. You can then select which columns you would like to compare in removing the dulicates.